# Função pra editar retornando NULL PHP e MYSQL

Tags: php, mysqli, php-7

Boa noite a todos,
sou novato em programação e estou seguindo um tutorial de criação de um sistema de controle de estoque.

```
    if(isset($_GET['id'])) {

      $idFabricante = $_GET['id'];

      var_dump($resp = $fabricante->EditFabricante($idFabricante));

    echo'  <div class="col-md-6">
          <!-- general form elements -->
          <div class="box box-primary">
            <div class="box-header with-border">
              <h3 class="box-title">Fabricante</h3>
            </div>
            <!-- /.box-header -->
            <!-- form start -->
            <form role="form" action="../../App/Database/insertfabricante.php" method="POST">
              <div class="box-body">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Nome da Empresa</label>
                  <input type="text" name="NomeFabricante" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Nome Fabricante" value="'.$resp['Fabricante']['Nome'].'">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="exampleInputEmail1">CNPJ</label>
                  <input type="text" name="CNPJFabricante" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="CNPJ" value="'.$resp['Fabricante']['CNPJ'].'">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="exampleInputEmail1">E-mail</label>
                  <input type="text" name="EmailFabricante" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="E-mail" value="'.$resp['Fabricante']['Email'].'">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Endereco</label>
                  <input type="text" name="EnderecoFabricante" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Endereço" value="'.$resp['Fabricante']['Endereco'].'">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Telefone</label>
                  <input type="text" name="TelefoneFabricante" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Telefone" value="'.$resp['Fabricante']['Telefone'].'">
                </div>
                <hr />
                <div class="box-header with-border">
              <h3 class="box-title">Representante</h3>
            </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Nome</label>
                  <input type="text" name="NomeRepresentante" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Nome do Representante">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Telefone</label>
                  <input type="text" name="TelefoneRepresentante" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Telefone">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="exampleInputEmail1">E-mail</label>
                  <input type="text" name="EmailRepresentante" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="E-mail ">
                </div>


                 <input type="hidden" name="iduser" value="'.$idUsuario.'">
                 <input type="hidden" name="idFabricante" value="'.$idFabricante.'">
              <!-- /.box-body -->

              <div class="box-footer">
                <button type="submit" name="upload" class="btn btn-primary" value="Cadastrar">Cadastrar</button>
                <a class="btn btn-danger" href="../../views/prod">Cancelar</a>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
          <!-- /.box -->
          </div>
</div>';
```

Estou tentando fazer com que, ao clicar em editar, preencha automaticamente os campos. Mas depois de usar `var_dump` está sempre retornando `NULL`.

Segue a `Function` com o `select`:

esse está dentro de uma class `fabricante.class.php`

```
public function EditFabricante($idFabricante){

  $this->query = "SELECT * FROM `fabricante` WHERE 'idFabricante'= 
  '$idFabricante'";

    if($this->result = mysqli_query($this->SQL, $this->query) or die ( 
       mysqli_error($this->SQL))){

      if($row = mysqli_fetch_array($this->result)){

          $NomeFabricante = $row['NomeFabricante'];
          $CNPJFabricante = $row['CNPJFabricante'];
          $EmailFabricante = $row['EmailFabricante'];
          $EnderecoFabricante = $row['EnderecoFabricante'];
          $TelefoneFabricante = $row['TelefoneFabricante'];
          $Usuario_idUser = $row['Usuario_idUser'];

        $array = array('Fabricante' => ['Nome' => $NomeFabricante, 'CNPJ' => $CNPJFabricante, 'Email' => $EmailFabricante, 'Endereco' => $EnderecoFabricante, 'Telefone' => $TelefoneFabricante, 'Usuario_idUser' =>$Usuario_idUser,]);

       return $array; 
      }

  }else{

    return 0;
  }

}
```

Se alguem puder dar uma força agradeço desde de já!

Answer (score 0):

Bom dia! O seu erro está na consulta MySQL. Pelo que me parece, você está transformando um campo 'idFabricante' do MySQL em um String, para arrumar isso você deve remover as aspas.

---

Aonde está: `$this->query = "SELECT * FROM fabricante WHERE 'idFabricante'='$idFabricante'";`

Substitua por:
 `$this->query = "SELECT * FROM fabricante WHERE idFabricante='$idFabricante'";`